# HTML5 Geolocation and a web app using a loading gif while waiting for gps co-ordinates

Tags: html, geolocation, loading, gif

Is there a way to use a animated gif while waiting for gps co-ordinates result?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use javascript to show the animated gif when you call getCurrentPosition() and hide it when you get the result. Example code below assumes you have the div in your HTML and are using jQuery.

```
    function startGeoLookup() {  
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handleGeoLookup);  
        $('#divGeoWait').show();
    }  

    function handleGeoLookup(position){  
        $('#divGeoWait').hide();
    }
```